# How do you get the US flag to display in the URL element of the MozBar?

Tags: seo

I just installed the MozBar chrome extension and I've been looking at Page Analysis of my website and other similar websites. I have noticed that the US flag shows up on many sites in front of the url when looking at the On-Page Elements of the MozBar.

However, when I look at the On-Page Elements of my website (zilchworks.com) no flag displays in front of the URL element?

How do I get the US flag to display within the MozBar?